# iMac headphone's external mic not work

Tags: macos, imac, headphones, microphone

I have 5 iMac in my office. We use skype for conversation. I have used almost 5 different brand's headphone but headphone's external mic not work at all.

I have checked sound settings. In the sound settings under "Input" section, when I select "Line in" for my headphone the mic does not work. But when I select "internal microphone" it works.

The same headphones are working perfectly on windows system.

Does iMac require any special headphones?

Comment: Did you check the sound settings and input source selection in Preferences?

Comment: Yes I have checked sound settings, In sound settings under "Input" section, when I select "Line in" for my headphone mic not work. But when I select "internal microphone" it works

Comment: How is the headset connected to your Mac, via audio cables or via USB?

Comment: Via audio cables, one for headphone and one for mic.

Comment: Do you see it in Skype set up ?

Comment: Yes i have checked it in skype too, "Line in" mic not work only  built-in Microphone works

Comment: Wait, so you see it in Skype set up but it will not work. So that tells us your system does recognizes the Input source.

Comment: Please use the @(my name) otherwise I do not get notification on your comments.

Comment: Just for fun, switch the cables.

Comment: @Buscar웃, ye my headphone is shown in skype settings as well as system settings but it doesn't work and as i told you have tried multiple headphones none of them work for me and all of them are perfectly working on windows system. As its office environment i have to speak loud to use iMac's internal mic which is not good for me :(

Comment: Welcome....I assume it is not MUTED ? Use Skype test call to verify.

Comment: @Buscar웃, yes i use skype test call. Moreover in iMac settings and skype settings there are indicator that shows voice input, both of them don't show any activity when i select my headphone's mic

Comment: Let me edit your question to get some more help in here.

Answer (score 2):

iMac line-in for Microphone is not powered!

Means you can not use a standard microphone.

It has to be one with power-source build in to the microphone.

In your case there are 3 choices.

Buy a line-in microphone with preamp.

Get a USB type Microphone (headset)

Cost reducing alternative:
If you have a Bluetooth headset for your phone (which you should if you making phone calls in the car), you can use it it 2.

Comment: You don't have to use the line-in, you can use the TRRS headphone port instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's iMacs use a 4-pin TRRS headphone port which combine analog audio output and input and need a connector like this:

[image]

(© wikipedia, user *Imaadwhd*)

Just take an adapter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SP0WAQ), plug in your headphones and mic, and it should work. I just verified this with my 2010 iMac. Another report stating the same can be found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5027869?tstart=0).

Unfortunately, Apple decided to not provide any documentation about that.

---

The same answer for a related question can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51376/70931).