# External Microphone input for MacBook Air 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, microphone

I am trying to get an external microphone ([this Sennheiser ME3](http://www.emicrophones.com/p-1085-sennheiser-me3-headset-microphone.aspx)) into the TRRS jack of my 2012 MacBook Air, through a headset splitter such as [here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Black-3-5mm-PC-Headset-to-Smart-Phone-Adapter-2-Female-to-Male-Splitter-Cable-/360697935154?pt=UK_Computing_Sound_Vision_Audio_Cables_Adapters&hash=item53fb45b532).

(this is so that I can use speech recognition software -- the Sennheiser is especially good for speech recognition)

The first check I do is on the headphones: I go to `System preferences -> Audio -> Output`, and notice that inserting the splitter registers as "Headphones/Headphone port" whereas removing it registers as "Internal speakers/built-in". So, that is behaving correctly.

I also note that actually plugging and unplugging headphones into the other end of the splitter doesn't register.

I also check that audio output works correctly TRRS -> splitter -> my headphones.

However, audio input does not behave correctly. `System preferences -> Audio -> Input` does not change when I plug and unplug the splitter (which has the Sennheiser ME3 attached). It states "Internal microphone/Built-in" regardless.

I've also done a simple experiment to confirm that the MacBook is indeed receiving audio from the built-in microphone. I.e. it is completely ignoring the fact that the Sennheiser is attached. I did this by launching QuickTime and creating audio recording, then putting on the Sennheiser and counting "123" with my face next to the screen then "456" with my head as far from the screen as the cable permits. The first recording comes out much louder, so it is indeed using the internal microphone.

How can I get to take input from the Sennheiser?

Related questions:

[MacBook Pro (mid-2012) Microphone Input](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90344/macbook-pro-mid-2012-microphone-input)

[MacBook Air audio input/output, mic/headset](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55446/macbook-air-audio-input-output-mic-headset)

[Recommendations for headset (+ mic ) for macbook in 2012](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51366/recommendations-for-headset-mic-for-macbook-in-2012)

[MacBook Air audio input/output, mic/headset](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55446/macbook-air-audio-input-output-mic-headset?rq=1)

PS If all else fails I will try [another splitter](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/3-5mm-Headphones-Headset-Microphone-Mic-Splitter-Lead-Cable-for-PC-Laptop-Tablet-/171085385766?pt=UK_MobilePhones_MobilePhoneAccesories_MobilePhoneDataCables_JN&hash=item27d57bd026).

Comment: It is the wrong splitter.

Comment: My gratitude to the people that took the care to tidy up my question. Typing is extremely painful to me due to RSI (I have to dictate using speech recognition, and formatting is a nightmare), and the help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using a splitter [Senneiser's page](http://en-uk.sennheiser.com/headworn-cardoid-microphone-headmic-singers-speakers-presenters-me-3-ew) shows a plug that looks like a headphone+mic combo which seems to be what the Air can take?

Comment: I submitted a fairly comprehensive answer below. I hope it's useful to somebody. Let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That ***TRRS*** socket actually has of odd configuration of ***4 pins*** so that you can use the genuine Apple headphone/microphone all-in-one ***4-pin*** combo that comes with iPods & iPhones etc. Generally they look like this: 
[image] [image]
Here is your microphone, right? The Sennheiser ME3. Notice there is a ***locking ring*** on that plug? Also, notice how there are two little black lines on the end there? That is the insulation separating the 3 conductive contacts aka ***3 pins*** This is a ***TRS*** plug: ( - )( + )(⏚).
[image: Sennheiser ME3]
It comes with the following caveats:

> ***1. The plug on your microphone has a rotating "locking ring", you have probably found that the microphone isn't working, or works only
>   sporadically depending on the connection. The issue is that locking
>   ring prevents the non-standard plug from fully engaging when plugging
>   into your sound card.***
>   ***2. Please note that all versions of the Sennheiser ME3 are wired differently than usual headset microphones and are not electrically
>   compatible with many computer sound cards.***

First of all, you're probably going to need something like this:
[image: ME3 Locking Ring Adapter]

> ***3. Additional Note:  This adapter does not change the unusual wiring scheme used by Sennheiser in the manufacture of the ME3.  The ME3 is not compatible with all sound cards.  If you are having trouble, we recommend you interface your ME3 with an external USB sound adapter, such as the Andrea Pure Audio (MA) adapter, Buddy 7G or the SpeechWare MultiAdapter.***

I don't know what's up with the strange wiring scheme. Maybe it's a stereo microphone, maybe it has something to do with their noise cancellation feature, maybe they use some weird shielding in their cable, maybe they're using balanced cables, maybe they just decided to use an odd wiring scheme and call it a proprietary connector, preventing people from using aftermarket accessories, maybe it was an accident. I can only speculate without digging deeper or seeing a schematic or something. If it were me, I would probably cut the plug off and wire it in a traditional manner. Apparently though, these are compatible with the ***Sennheiser ME3.*** They are known as The ***Andrea Pure Audio USB-SA Adapter*** *&* The ***Andrea Pure Audio USB-MA Adapter***, respectively.

[image] [image]

If by some miracle you have an ordinary connector, or you find a suitable line-level adapter to make things "normal", you're probably still going to want one of these;
***1/8" TRRS male to 1/8" TS female input & 1/8" TRS female adapters:***[image: TRRS male to 1/8" TS female input & 1/8" TRS female output]
Yes, it looks and sounds weird. The ***4-conductor TRRS plug*** on this cable uses the ***CTIA*** standard configuration, which puts the microphone signal on the sleeve (versus being on the second ring in the *OMTP* standard). The ***CTIA*** standard has always been used by ***Apple*** and ***HTC***, while *older* *Samsung, Nokia & Sony Ericsson* devices (for instance) initially used the *OMTP* standard.

Plug the 3.5mm (1/8") ***male TRRS*** plug into the audio jack on your laptop.
The smaller of the two 3.5mm (1/8") ***female*** jack bodies is the ***TRS*** stereo headphone output. Plug your standard earphones, headphones, speakers, or other output device into this jack.
The larger of the two 3.5mm (1/8") ***female*** jack bodies is the ***TS*** mono microphone input. Plug your (hopefully, now) *"standard PC style microphone cable"* into this jack.

Answer (score 1):

I asked tech support at [emicrophones.com](http://emicrophones.com) and got the following super-helpful answer:

> Unfortunately, the MBA is looking for a line-in voltage, not a mic-in
>   voltage. There is no good way to directly connect a microphone to the
>   audio port on the MBA, you must go through a USB adapter. In theory,
>   you could use a pre-amp, but I haven’t seen one that has the right
>   connections and is portable and/or cost-effective. Something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5mm-MONO-JACK-MICROPHONE-PLUG-POWER-BATTERY-MODULE-/270787690564?pt=UK_MusicalInstruments_Other_Pro_Audio_Equipment&hash=item3f0c344044)
>   might work, but I haven’t found a local source for them to test. You
>   would also lose the benefit of ADC algorithms specifically designed
>   for speech recognition if you use an internal sound card.

EDIT: I have just discovered that plugging in a stock 3-band-plug Apple headset (such as http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MD827ZM/A/apple-earpods-with-remote-and-mic?fnode=49) ***does indeed get recognised*** as an external microphone.

So it cannot be as simple as "TRRS Mic input is line level"

This headset is obviously unpowered. Therefore somehow the MacBook's TRRS must have some way of determining what is plugged into it, and switching between powered / unpowered operation.

And my Sennheiser ME3 is failing to trigger this switch.

Comment: Your answer is confusing and conflicting, please consider revising. Please pay attention to the number of rings in the connector.

Comment: @Buscar, I have edited my answer. The reality appears to me to be confusing and conflicting. I'm scratching my head here.

Answer (score 0):

I following instructions from https://discussions.apple.com/message/22615803#22615803 I was able to connect an external microphone to my MB Air 2013 by pressing volume down button on my dr Dre headset. Unfortunately buttons on the headset doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

According to the page that you referenced for the mic, it states that:

> Please note that all versions of the Sennheiser ME3 (sold here or
>   elsewhere) are wired differently than usual headset microphones and
>   are not electrically compatible with many computer sound cards

**This explains the issue that you are experiencing.**

Further, they go on to say:

> This microphone is completely functional, however, when used in
>   conjunction with an Andrea USB sound adapter, the Buddy 6G or 7G USB
>   adapter, and the Andrea Pure Audio USB Adapter. We recommend
>   purchasing our "ME3 combo" (pictured above) for predictably great
>   results.

I suggest getting the [Andrea Pure Audio USB Adapter](https://store.speechrecsolutions.com/andrea-pureaudio-usb-ma-adapter-p28.aspx?Thread=True)

Is there a reason you need this splitter for a microphone?  I didn't get that from your description of the problem.

**EDIT:**

I noticed in one of the comments you said you didn't want to use up one of the USB ports.  Have a look at these USB Hubs by [Anker.](http://amzn.to/1CuAhpI)  I personally use these and I can attest to their customer service - their return and support policy is beyond fantastic.