# Mac Desktop not detecting microphone

Tags: audio, microphone

I have an External (XLR) SDMP15 Stagg mic that comes with a 3,5m XLR to phone plug 6,35 mm and I also bought a Bespeco Adaptor in hopes of recording audio. However, when I plug it all together (the mic connects to the cable and the other side of the cable to the adaptor which then connects to my Mac Desktop via the Headphone port) the mic isn't detected in Preferences > Sound. Only the internal mic shows up and basically the mic only emits sound as it is connected to the Headphone port.

My Mac doesn't realise that it serves an an input device and I don't know what more I have to do.

[image: my mic] [image: my cable]
[image: my adaptor]

Comment: You have the wrong adaptor - that's a TRS to twin TRS. I don't actually know what plug the iMac needs [I've never owned one] but it's not going to be that one, might need TRRS - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99304/external-microphone-input-for-macbook-air-2012 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90344/macbook-pro-mid-2012-microphone-input?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense that I need a TRRS adaptor because I went to check my Iphone's headphones and they have 3 rings on them so that must mean something. These FNAC employees are so clueless they told me that my adaptor was gonna work for sure smh